# Nested JSON in dataview with Sencha Architect

Tags: json, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I want to display nested JSON data in a dataview in my Sencha Touch 2 project. The JSON contains details of a servicerequest with progress.

The JSON:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Request retrieved with id:789",
    "data": {
        "id": 789,
        "description": "request description",
        "subject": "request subject",
        "progresses": [
            {
                "description": "progress description 1"
            },
            {
                "description": "progress description 2"
            },
            {
                "description": "progress description 3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

For getting the data, I have two models, one for the requestdetails, one for the progress and of course a store.

My store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.RequestStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.RequestModel'
    ],
    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        model: 'MyApp.model.RequestModel'
    }
});
```

And my models:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.RequestModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    uses: [
        'MyApp.model.ProgressModel'
    ],
    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'id'
            },
            {
                name: 'description'
            },
            {
                name: 'subject'
            }
        ],
        hasMany: {
            associationKey: 'progresses',
            model: 'MyApp.model.ProgressModel'
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: 'http://myurl.com/rest/request/789',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'data'
            }
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.ProgressModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    uses: [
        'MyApp.model.RequestModel'
    ],
    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'description'
            }
        ],
        belongsTo: {
            model: 'MyApp.model.RequestModel'
        }
    }
});
```

This is my view:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyDataView', {
extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',

config: {
    store: 'RequestStoreId',
    itemTpl: [
        '<div>',
        '   <div>ID</div>',
        '   <div>{id}</div>',
        '           ',
        '   <div>Subject</div>',
        '   <div>{subject}</div>',
        '           ',
        '   <div>Description</div>',
        '   <div>{description}</div>',
        '</div>',
        '',
        '<h2><b>Progress:</b></h2>',
        '<tpl for="progressmodels">',
        '    <div>',
        '        <div>{description}</div>',
        '    </div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ]
}
});
```

Displaying the `id`, `requestType`, `description` and `subject` works fine. In case of the progress, I want all progressdescription to be shown, but only the first description is displayed now.

I tried a lot and search the internet to solve it, but I can't figure out what it is.

What am I doing wrong here? Do I miss something? Are there people with the same problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you find any solution yet? I'm also have the same problem as you

Comment: Yes I have. `<tpl for="progresses">` worked for me instead of `<tpl for="progressmodels">`. Only problem is that you can't convert the data in the progresses nodes (eg dates) in the model. You have to do this in the Xtemplate itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing

`<tpl for="progressmodels">`

with

`<tpl for="progresses">`

worked for me. The `progresses` node is the node I want to loop. Only disadvantage is that you can't convert the data in the node with your model. You have to do this in your XTemplate as far as I know :)

Hope this will help someone!

Comment: By default the root node name should be a pluralised version of target model name, but not necessarily. You can also specify 'root' config parameter for your Reader to override it (and stick to 'progresses' in this case).